# Propel is not returning all the rows

Tags: php, postgresql, propel

I'm trying to execute a query using propel and it should return 50 rows of data, but instead of that it returns other random number of rows. I printed the query copied in my pgphpadmin and it returns the 50 rows. I'm not sure what is happening. Also if I execute "count" function before "find" it returns 50, but after it returns the random amount of rows.

```
$limit = 50;
$offset = 0;
..... //filters 
$companies = $companies->orderById()->limit($limit)->offset($offset);
var_dump($companies->count()); // this returns 50
$companies = $companies->find();
var_dump($companies->count()); // this returns 13
```

Also the foreach after iterates only 13 times.

And this is the query generated

```
SELECT "company"."id", "company"."otherfields",
"lists"."id", "lists"."otherfields", "place"."id",
"place"."otherfields", "contact"."id", "contact"."otherfields", 
"entry"."id","entry"."otherfields" 
FROM "company" LEFT JOIN "lists" ON 
("company"."sector_id"="lists"."id") LEFT JOIN "place" ON 
("company"."country_id"="place"."id") LEFT JOIN "contact" ON  
("company"."id"="contact"."company_id" AND "contact"."active" = true)
LEFT JOIN "entry" ON ("company"."id"="entry"."company_id") 
WHERE "company"."active"=true ORDER BY "company"."id" ASC LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
```

The Propel version is 2.0-dev

I always had a problem with this query so I think that the problem may come from the fact that I removed one **throw** in the library. I'm using with() and limit().  The query generated is ok, but the result is not.

Changed Propel/Runtime/Formatter/ObjectFormatter.php
I've commented this.

```
/*if ($this->hasLimit) {
            throw new LogicException('Cannot use limit() in conjunction with with() on a one-to-many relationship. Please remove the with() call, or the limit() call.');
}*/
```

I imagine that the error might come from here.

My join query looks like this

```
$companies->leftJoinWithLists()->leftJoinWithPlace()->leftJoinWithContact()->addJoinCondition('Contact','Contact.active = ?', true)->leftJoinWithEntry();
```

And then I add the limit. Any way to avoid this or do it other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any way to avoid this or do it another way?

You need to do it a different way.  See my comment on the issue you created at https://github.com/propelorm/Propel2/issues/1231

Basically, the `LIMIT` clause in SQL will limit the number of rows in the result set, but since you are using a `LEFT JOIN`, one company entity may be represented in multiple rows of the result set (see the raw result in pgphpadmin).

The solution: Use multiple queries.  I suggest querying first for all the companies you want, then using the `->populateRelation()` method on the resulting `ObjectCollection`.